# typescript access global variable inside listener

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an Angular 2 project and am wanting to test event listeners. 
this is defined

```
map;
```

then in a populate map method i have

```
  populateMap() {


var place = { lat: -17.822828, lng: -31.046727 };
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: place,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  },
  maxZoom: 19
});


this.map.addListener('click', function (e) {
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: e.latLng,
    map: this.map
  });
  this.map.panTo(e.latLng);
});


this.map.fitBounds(this.bounds);
this.map.panToBounds(this.bounds);
}
```

an exception is thrown in the listener of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'panTo' of undefined
```

Is there a reason why javascript is unable to find the correct "this.map" reference, forgot to mention, this is Google Maps API v3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are inside of a different context and thus `this` does not refer to the outer context. You have to keep a reference to it e.g.

```
var self = this;
this.map.addListener('click', function (e) {
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: e.latLng,
    map: self.map
  });
  self.map.panTo(e.latLng);
});
```